# Images either side of a header

Tags: html, css, image

I've found a few answers to this question, but I can't seem to find a solution that works for me. As a school project, we need to create websites, and I decided to help my friend with hers.

So, what I'm trying to do is this:
[What She Designed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyJL6.png)

What I'm getting is this:
[My Best Effort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oloQi.png)

My HTML:

```
            <div class="top">
                <image class ="logo1" src="Assets/FINAL LOGO.png" width="100" height="150" alt="Suit Up Logo">
                <h1 class="title">Suit Up</h1>
                <image class ="logo2" src="Assets/FINAL LOGO.png" width="100" height="150" alt="Suit Up Logo">
            </div>
```

My Css:

```
.top{
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
min-height: 70px;
padding-top: 30px;
}
header{
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.logo1{
  float: left;
}
.logo2{
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please use the snippet tool to create a runnable snippet for your html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add the following in your css file.

```
.title{
 display: inline;}
```

Comment: Ah, great. Thank you!